# Configuration of upload_max_filesize using .htacess gives 500 server error

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a problem, I m using a shared Linux server, I want to upload file of size around 10-100MB. I don't have access to php.ini file.

```
 ini_set('post_max_size', '64M');
 ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '64M');
```

It didn't works on server.

Therefore I tried another way using `.htacess` by creating a file on root directory and placing the following code

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 40M
php_value post_max_size 42M
```

But it gives my 500 Internal Server Error.

Is there something wrong I am doing?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you get 500 Server Error, it means that your sharing host is not letting you to set these global configuration.  Contact your hosting company and ask them to set `AllowOverride` Options for your host.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your shared hosting is running PHP as CGI/FastCGI and not as an apache module. You can put php configuration inside an `.htaccess` file only if apache is running PHP as a module.

Also, for these settings to have effect, it will depend on the `AllowOverride` setting in the main apache config file, as Faron said in his answer.